# Adding images through the new Freebase UI doesn't work

Tags: freebase

For some Freebase topics, there are no images available (e.g. for https://www.freebase.com/m/0399p ) and in some cases I have images available which I would like to add to Freebase since they are being used in our website.

Since Freebase updated its UI this month, trying to add values to /common/topic/image through the Freebase UI (link mentioned above) returns the error "*Add image not yet implemented*".

Is there an update as to when adding images to topics will be supported again? Or is there any other way of uploading them to Freebase?

Answer (score 3):

The only way that Freebase is loading new images is from Wikipedia right now. If the feature gets added it won't be for a while so I'd recommend that you host your own images right now. Sorry for the inconvenience but there are a lot of complicated issues with image licenses and fair use.