# Freebase: how do you upload or link images to a topic?

Tags: freebase

I'm trying to add an image to this Freebase Topic: https://www.freebase.com/m/0w7kcd6?props= (The image I want to add is the image currently used in the linked wikipedia article, as well as the signature). The menu to the left of `/common/topic/image` that appears when clicking on the yellow down arrow doesn't provide any option. Here [Adding images through the new Freebase UI doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693171/adding-images-through-the-new-freebase-ui-doesnt-work) a user answers that you can upload from Wikipedia, but how do you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Freebase doesn't allow uploading of images any more.  If they still upload images from Wikipedia, it's at their discretion, not based on any type of external signal.